# How to port-forward from a mobile hotspot to a device on its local LAN?

Tags: tcp, ip, port, router, hotspot

I'm trying to practice tcp-ip, where the only network I have are built on mobile wifi, where the mobile phones are "tethered" as a hotspot.

In order to simulate (for study) a "router", i have 2 computers connected to 2 different mobile phones...which now i try to solve, how to send data from one computer to the other.

I was successful only when both computers were on the same LAN (i.e. connected to the same "hotspot", i.e. the same mobile device), where I've done the usual socket()+bind()+listen()+accept() for the "server", and socket()+connect()+write() on the "client", using the 192.168.43.24 for server and 192.168.43.25 (the exact suffix for tne netmask, just happens to be my current config, i.e. "24" for server and "25" for client), but im not sure how do i send data from a local computer behind a mobile hotspot to a computer behind another hotspot?

If this is a case for port-forwarding, i don't see how i can control my mobile phone acting as a "router" (i.e. hotspot), and change its settings.
thanks